# How does a snowflake "know" to form symmetrically?

Tags: water, symmetry, crystals, freezing, ice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are snowflakes symmetrical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/why-are-snowflakes-symmetrical)

Under ideal situations, a snowflake forms into near perfect hexagonal symmetry. How? For instance, when a water molecule moves towards the edge of the snowflake, how does it "know" where to place itself so that the crystal formed matches the other five points?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3795/2451